# Android UI does not get refreshed with Data from DB

Tags: android

I am creating an activity which paints the UI (TableLayout displayed with data from MYSQL database). The UI has a button so on clicking that, it takes to a different activity and then it comes back to the parent. My issue is that, when it comes back to the parent, the parent screen does not show the updated data.

to be more clear, the parent is a view screen with an add button. Clicking on Add button takes to a form where the user fills in data and submits. After submit of the Add screen, the parent screen(view screen) is invoked again. Here the table layout is not refreshed with the newly added record.

Kindly help me as am struggling with this for days now.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to help you without seeing any of your code. You can try this approach:

Put the code that fetches the MySQL data and updates yout TableLayout inside the `onResume()` method of your "view activity". This way this view will be updated when the user comes back to it after filling the form.

Check this page for more information on [Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

I t depends on how you fill your ListView. If you are using Loaders and CursorAdapter than you should call swapCursor() method of you CursorAdapter. This will allow Listview to repaint itself with new data from updated cursor.